# Does t-function from i18next support plurals?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I need to make a string plural-aware:

```js
const count = getSuppliersCount();
console.log(t('We found {{count}} suppliers', { count }))
```

so that it'd output either 'suppliers' or 'supplier' depending on the `count`.

I tried so far something like this:

```js
t('asd', {
  count: count,
  one: 'We found {{count}} supplier',
  other: 'We found {{count}} suppliers'
})
```

but it didn't work, only printing 'asd'.

Note that I cannot use any external locales-file, like it's shown [in the docs](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/plurals), because we maintain default English translations **right in the code**. And I'm struggling to find a way to make my string plural.